# Which algorithm should I use to analyze the relation between all commodities?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

So now I have a list of commodities which bought by many different people.

```
1. bread, bear, egg, apple
2. carrot, water, glasses
3. apple, egg, bottle
4. meat, egg, soup, juice
5. water, carrot, bear
6. apple, carrot, water
....
```

I want to know which commodity combo is most popular.

The output of my example is likely this:

```
carrot, water
```

because they are bought together more popular by other commodities combo.

I know the algorithm might be belong to Data Mining.

However, I don't know what the keyword is.

I only need the keyword (maybe the algorithm name) and I will do the research by myself!

Thank you all. :)

Comment: It's possible to do this with map reduce if you generate all permutations of your items

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, I will do research on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the subdomain known as

## Frequent Itemset Mining

in particular, the algorithm APRIORI.

Comment: I think this is what I want! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The lecture [Frequent Itemsets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch6.pdf)
 from stanford CS246 courese may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing!